# CoreData inserting and immediate delete: memory usage grows and grows

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-leaks

I put a test app together, pretty straight forward from the starting point of a Command Line Tool with Core Data enabled project. ARC is enabled.

It basically creates an entity, saves it, retrieves all entities from the context and deletes them.

**What I don't understand, why is the memory usage growing and growing?**
Thanks for the clarification.

This is the test program:

#### main.m

```
#import "Message.h"

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel(void);
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext(void);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

        @autoreleasepool {
            while(true){
                // Create the managed object context
                NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

                Message *message = [NSEntityDescription
                                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Message" 
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
                message.string = @"A string";

                // Save the managed object context
                NSError *error = nil;    
                if (![context save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
                    exit(1);
                }

                // Load and delete object from context
                NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Message" 
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
                [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
                NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
                for (Message *message in fetchedObjects) {
                    NSLog(@"String is: %@", message.string);
                    [context deleteObject: message];
                    [context save: &error];
                }

                sleep(0.005);
            }
        }
    return 0;
}

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel() {

    static NSManagedObjectModel *model = nil;

    if (model != nil) {
        return model;
    }

    NSString *path = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"momd"]];
    model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return model;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext() {

    static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    if (context != nil) {
        return context;
    }

    @autoreleasepool {
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel()];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

        NSString *STORE_TYPE = NSSQLiteStoreType;

        NSString *path = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]];

        NSError *error;
        NSPersistentStore *newStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:STORE_TYPE configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error];

        if (newStore == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Store Configuration Failure %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        }
    }
    return context;
}
```

#### Message.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Message : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * string;

@end
```

#### Message.m

```
#import "Message.h"


@implementation Message

@dynamic string;

@end
```

Comment: You don't release fetchRequest in while loop, which creates one instance every .005 seconds and just leaks it. Also running static analyzer might show you some other memory leaks (if present).

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
```

that is never released, you should try to initialize it as an autorelease

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Ok I added autorelease, but this doesn't make any difference.
I also tried calling release right before the sleep command, but this has also no effect on the memory usage.

I'm a bit confused about how ARC handles the memory. I have lots of experience in many programming languages, but am pretty new to objective c, and its even more confusing that the docs you read are all written for different memory handling approaches. But as far as I understood it, you don't have to call any (auto)release statements when using ARC? Is that right?

Comment: uhm.. strange, did u try to run your application along with the profiler, to look at mem allocs and leaks?

Comment: I'm trying to get some useful information from the profiler, but I don't really know what I should look for.

I'm looking at Statistics->Object Summary
The two most memory consuming entries there are Malloc 32 Bytes and __NSArrayM. If I click the arrow right next the names I get a listing where they were created?! By far the most callers is NSManagedObjectContext.
For the third entry it is NSUndoManager.

Would screenshots be helpful, or should I archive the project and upload it?